# Is a radix tree (Patricia Trie) an efficient data structre for a mobile-phone address book

Tags: c++, addressbook, trie

I have been thinking on implementing an address book in C++. Since it's developed for mobile application the address book should use as less memory as possible and also the user should still be able to search or sort contacts by name fast ( paradox I know ).

After I've researched a bit I found that most of the people suggest that a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be the best data structure tp fit my needs. More precisely a [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)( Patricia Trie ). Using this data structure would also be great for implementing autocomplete too.

Are there other viable solutions or is it ok if I start coding using this idea ?

Comment: About how much entries are we talking here? And how fast is the mobile device? Is it really worth implementing a complex data structure?

Comment: Regular address book size. I guess no one would have more than let's say 5000 contacts ( tops )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of tries for small collections. Though they do offer good asymptotical behavior, their hidden constant in both time and space might be too big.

Especially, tries tend to have poor **cache performace, which should be the main concern for small collections**.

Assuming your data is relatively small [<10,000 entries], a `std::vector` can offer good cache performance, which will probably be much more influence then the size factor. So even the search time for it is asymptotically higher then trie or a std::set, practically - it might be better then both, thanks to good caching behavior.

If you can also maintain the `vector` sorted, using [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) - you can benefit from both logarithmic search time and good cache behavior.

(*)This answer assumes the hardware where the app will be deployed on has [CPU-Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache).

Comment: Is a binary search on a vector necessarily any worse for cache hits than navigating a trie?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I believe it is, assuming the collection is small - it [`vecotr`] might actually fit in cache. tries [even radix tries] tend to have a lot of overhead, and therefore is much more likely to "overflow" the cache. For small collections, this difference might be much more significant then the asymptotical behavior

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, the extra overhead on the Trie. Now that you've pointed out the cache can have a huge difference ( don't know why I didn't thought about that ) I'm looking completely different at this problem.

Comment: @QtLearner: Your thinking was very correct, and it was the suggestion I'd give you, for a large collection. However, for small collections, the asymptotic behavior is usually not the issue, the constant factors [and bad cache performance is concidered as such] are most likely to have much more effect.

Answer (score 0):

tries are the best for such purpose as they offer quick search,insertiona and deletion.